# alert Optgroup onclick in IE11

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

The requirement is to get an alert both on click of the `optgroup` and `option`. The first half of the jQuery works in Chrome and it gives alert when clicked either on optgroup or option.

The second half of the jQuery, that is the function, is for the IE11 and it alerts only the options. How can i make this function throw alert even on click of the optgroup?

```js
$('.optgroup').click(function() {
  alert("hello");
  $('option', this).slideToggle()
});

(function($) {
  $(document).on('change', '#BodyContentPlaceHolder_UCInstanceList_lstInstance', function() {
    alert("hello");
  });
}(jQuery));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select size="10" class="OptSel">
  <optgroup class="optgroup" label="Label1">
    <option value="Option1" title="Title1">Option1</option>
    <option value="Option2" title="Title2">Option2</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup class="optgroup" label="Label2">
    <option value="Option3" title="Title3">Option3</option>
    <option value="Option4" title="Title4">Option4</option>
    <option value="Option5" title="Title5">Option5</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup class="optgroup" label="Label3">
    <option value="Option6" title="Title6">Option6</option>
    <option value="Option7" title="Title7">Option7</option>
  </optgroup>      
</select>
```

Comment: Try to refer this link may help to solve the issue. Ref: https://www.ryadel.com/en/jquery-cross-browser-hide-option-and-optgroup-select-html-element/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your purpose is just to display the alert() while clicking on **optgroup** or **option** than try to refer example below may help you to solve the issue for IE.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

 $("select").click(function() {
        
        alert("Hello...");


    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<select size="10" class="OptSel">
  <optgroup class="optgroup" label="IT">
    <option value="AVMDem" title="AVM Demo">AVM Demo</option>
    <option value="Info" title="Information Technology">Information Technology</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup class="optgroup" label="KT SR">
    <option value="KTSR" title="KT on SR Module">KT on SR Module</option>
    <option value="MSD" title="MSD">MSD</option>
    <option value="newtes" title="newtesting">newtesting</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup class="optgroup" label="Infrastructure">
    <option value="RBA" title="RBA Tenant">RBA Tenant</option>
    <option value="SRTent" title="SR Tenant">SR Tenant</option>
  </optgroup>
  <option selected="selected" value="Val" title="Validation Tenant">Validation Tenant</option>
</select>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How do i make it work only for the optgroup?

Comment: There is no any direct way specifically for IE browser. If possible for your than you can try to store the text of the optgroup in variables and try to match it when user clicks on it. If both get match than you can display the alert otherwise you can avoid to display alert. This can be the possible work around for IE only.